# Parent Entity is not populated in @OneToMany. Hibernate Bidirectional

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

hi newbie to Hibernate,

My entity classes

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue//How to restrcit by passing id from response
    @JsonIgnore
    private Integer userId;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
    private List<PostEntity> postEntity;

}



@Entity
@Table(name="post")
public class PostEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @JsonIgnore
    @ApiModelProperty(required=false)
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private User user;
}
```

When I fetch User its populating Post entity as well.

URI: http://localhost:8080/jpa/users

```
[
 {
     "name": "Abdul",
     "birthDate": "2018-07-25T01:29:51.895+0000",
     "postEntity": [
         {
             "description": "My Fourth Post"
         },
         {
             "description": "My First Post"
         },
         {
             "description": "My Second Post"
         }
     ]
 },
 {
     "name": "Anji",
     "birthDate": "2018-07-25T01:29:51.903+0000",
     "postEntity": []
 },
 {
     "name": "Naren",
     "birthDate": "2018-07-25T01:29:51.903+0000",
     "postEntity": []
 }
]
```

but this is not the case in reverse. When I fetch post its skipping User entity.

URI: localhost:8080/jpa/users/101/posts/11001
Response:

```
{
    "description": "My First Post"
}
```

Why its not populating user information in the above JSON response.

Fetching Methods:

User:

```
@GetMapping("/jpa/users")
public List<User> retAll(){
    return userRepository.findAll();
}
```

Post:

```
@GetMapping("/jpa/users/{uid}/posts/{pid}")
public Resource<PostEntity> postE(@PathVariable int uid,@PathVariable int pid) {
    Optional<PostEntity> post = postRepository.findById(pid);
    if (!post.isPresent()) {
        throw new UserNotFoundException("POst");
    }

    PostEntity ePost = post.get();
    Resource<PostEntity> resource = new Resource<PostEntity>(ePost);
    return resource;
}
```

Please help.

Comment: This depends on how you are fetching. If you are fetching it in one transaction it will work fine.

Comment: do you have a `getUser` methd in PostEntity?

Comment: I have proper getters and setters. I have not posted though.

Answer (score 3):

That is actually the intended way REST is supposed to work.

`GET` at `/users` : all users

`GET` at `/users/1` : information of user 1 and all its children

`GET` at `/users/1/posts` : all posts of user 1

`GET` at `/users/1/posts/10` : information of post 10 and all its children from user 1

As you're calling `/users/101/posts/11001`, the endpoint will give you the information of **one** post (id 11001) from one user (id 101).

There are two common ways to get the parent information:

The fastest way would be to just call `/users` and filter for your desired post in the frontend.

The *right* way would be changing the model of your post (`PostEntity.java`) to contain its "parent" `User` object, so when you make a REST call for a post, the user object gets populated.

Further reading:

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/274998/nested-rest-urls-and-parent-id-which-is-better-design

Maybe it's a good idea to read some REST best practices:

https://hackernoon.com/restful-api-designing-guidelines-the-best-practices-60e1d954e7c9

Comment: Fine. Is there any way to populate parent entity if child entity is requested?

Comment: @Abdul Updated my answer.

Comment: So, do you want me to remove @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY) from PostEntity now?

Comment: i'm not sure, but I think this only work if using spring-data-rest and @RestRepository annotation, which don't seems to be the case.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use FetchType

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue//How to restrcit by passing id from response
    @JsonIgnore
    private Integer userId;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<PostEntity> postEntity;

}
```

Beware of the performance.